# polygonal chain approximation to a continuous curve

Tags: calculus

can you help me prove that every continuous curve in R^n has a sequence of polygonal chains which converge to it?

Comment: What is a chain in this context? Piecewese definition? And what kind of convergence?

Comment: well, this is polygonal chain: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polygonal_chain and if we define the curve as an image of a continuous function F from [0,1] to R^n, and the nth polygonal as an image of a continuous function g(n): from [0,1] to R^n, than convergence of the sequence of the polygonal chains to F, means that for every t in [0,1], g(n) (t) approaches F(t) as n approaches infinity.

Comment: Do you know that if $f:[0,1]\to \mathbb R^n$ is continuous then it is uniformly continuous?